# vbscript minus operator marked as invalid character

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a very simple equation in vbscript/asp. I get error on **minus** operator. I even had to add 0 in start of equation because I got same error at first one too.

```
y = 0 - (0.0114 * (x^2)) − (0.2396 * x) + 112.57
```

> Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0408'
>
> Invalid character
>
> y = 0-(0.0114 * (x^2))-(0.2396 * x)+112.57
>
> ----------------------------^

Comment: Try putting space before/after the caret sign i.e. instead of `(x^2)`, do `(x ^ 2)`. I tried this in VBA but I am assuming it will work with vbscript too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character between the `x^2))` and the `(0.2396` does not look like the character between the `0` and the `(0.0114`. It is likely an en dash, not a minus/hyphen. Fix that. ***Do not use Word or other word processor for creating code; the smart replacement of dashes and quotes will cause problems with code. Use a text editor like Notepad or Notepad++ instead.***

Comment: Thank you. To make it more clear I had made a copy of formula from web to my code editor. The source of problem was not the code  editor itself but that character was not originally the minus character.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Nothing obvious then, not like people just blindly copy from the web and don't expect formatting issues.